# IntelliJ Idea - No files were downloaded for junit:junit:5.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

Have little exposure to Maven and other external libraries. Junit worked fine just a week ago, possibly affected by an update? Can't be sure, same error happens when attempting to install other versions.

**10:08 p.m. Repository library synchronization: No files were downloaded for junit:junit:5.0-SNAPSHOT**

Again, it worked just fine a week ago, here are the tests - https://github.com/Ry4nW/CS-11-VLN/blob/main/CS%2011%20VLN/IntegerSetTest/TestCases/IntegerSetTests.java

Comment: You have to use 5.7.1 or alike but not SNAPSHOT versions because they are not available in general ... check the docs for the correct versions https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configured your dependency wrong. According to your test you're using JUnit 4. Your dependency should be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit<artifactId>
    <version>4.13.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

There is no version 5.x of junit:junit. JUnit 5 uses different group and artifact IDs. E.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The same thing happens when I try to install it on another project; is it possibly something else? If not, how do I edit my dependencies?

Comment: There is a file `pom.xml` that should list your dependencies. I also recommend to read at least a short introduction to Maven. This will help you to understand the problem and there is a good chance that you can solve it on your own.